# How much information about my job should I reveal on my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, ethics, linkedin, job-description

I am drafting my current job description for my LinkedIn page. I want to showcase certain projects that I worked on with my team, but I'm not sure if it is "acceptable" to disclose them in my description.

The projects themselves are non-confidential, meaning I didn't sign anything saying they were. Also, they don't disclose any company secret or anything of the sort.

Regardless, I am stumped on how to approach this and how to describe my projects without getting into too many details.

Example project: I worked on implementing an LCD screen functionality for the company's product.
Should I just describe it like *that*? Or should I add more information? Or less information?
Another example: I worked with other developers to implement an entirely new framework for testing the product.

I would love some input, and if possible some examples.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had some experience in this area. I'll try to give you some guidelines.

1. You can share information based on any data that is available online, on the company's website, their publications or any such sources.
2. You can share general information which is clearly visible. E.g. - If your company makes calculators you can definitely mention you worked on the LCD or so.
3. Never mention anything implementation specific. Don't mention things that aren't directly available like specifications, part numbers, component numbers, any IP your company has invented.

In your examples,

1. Mentioning that you worked on LCD displays is fine. You can mention additional detail but only regarding your work-role in it, like:

   > I was (a part of team) responsible for adding new features and fixing defects in the LCD displays of T1000 model calculators
2. Second example: Exactly as is. Avoid any additional details about the framework itself.

I hope my answer helped.

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 levels in your question : legal, & useful(for your job hunt, good luck btw).

For the legal part, well, just remove anything you cannot say. I worked on marketing projects for banks, for targetting prospects, I can write that, but no way you'll hear me speaking about the real strategies for targetting prospects. This is covered by the professional secret.

For the useful part, be sure to know who you are speaking to. I switched job for a medical oriented firm, whose customers are hospitals, not individuals. I just wrote "worked on marketing", and insisted on technical qualities instead. OTOH, had I targetted a marketing service in another bank, I would have said as much as possible "Worked on prospect targetting, helped set up new targetting methods".....etc... But staying still in the dark about methods. That's a legal requirement.

Back to your question, for the framework example : as long as you don't give away trade secrets(and there is not much secret in a testing framework), you can give away as much details as you want - as long as they are of interest for your prospective employer.

LCD screens are probably more protected(simple guess from me, I don't know that domain), and be more careful, but if your prospective employer is building LCDs too or similar devices, make him salivate : "implemented a dynamic menu with improved ergonomy and adaptative color"(I'm inventing on the fly, just an example), or whatever he can think is useful. If it's an accounding company, be more light: "worked with such language on LCD screen management".